# Is the Hebrew in Job 33:27 subjunctive?

Tags: hebrew, grammar, job

KJV translates Job 33:27 as

> He looketh upon men, and if any say, I have sinned, and perverted that which was right, and it profited me not;

ESV translates

> He sings before men and says:
> ‘I sinned and perverted what was right,
> and it was not repaid to me.

What is the reason for KJV translating this in the subjunctive "if any say..."?

Comment: There is no such thing as subjunctive in Hebrew.  The KJV is essentially alone in expressing the subjunctive in English - i could not find another that did the same.  The words in the KJV "if any say" are added and not in the Hebrew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entirety of 23-38 follow an if statement:

33:23 (NIV) reading:

> Yet if there is an angel at their side,
> a messenger, one out of a thousand,
> sent to tell them how to be upright,

And the hypothetical man begins a few verses earlier at nineteen.

The core question is "who is He who looks upon men?" - and the grammar doesn't help - with the KJV translators going with God thus obliging them to add some sort of italic text to keep God from also being He confessing sins.

Another difficulty, is the next verse:

> פָּדָ֣ה [נַפְשִׁי כ] (נַ֭פְשֹׁו ק) מֵעֲבֹ֣ר בַּשָּׁ֑חַת [וְחַיָּתִי כ] (וְ֝חַיָּתֹו ק) בָּאֹ֥ור תִּרְאֶֽה׃

You may notice those brackets. They aren't normal, what this means is that the Hebrew text is itself difficult to make out. The KJV went with "He will redeem* his soul" * being forced to by the earlier if. While more modern translations say "He has redeemed my soul".

The vulgate uses "his" for 28. However, the Septuagint uses "my". And both Septuagint and Vulgate translate 27 as the saved man giving his testimony, but the KJV translators went with their Hebrew texts.

Essentially, the KJV had limited information and had to make some jumps and compromises to fit around the awkwardness with what they had. However, it looks like - as we've got more evidence - that they made wrong choices.